# Json Object split into json string

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below data is my json object

```
var column = {
    "SNo": [{ "group": "true", "sort": "true", "filter": "true", "type": "number", "min": 1, "max": 1000, "format": "{0:c}"}],
    "Name": [{ "group": "true", "sort": "true", "type": "string", "columnmenu": "true"}],
    "City": [{ "group": "true", "type": "number", "filter": "true", "width": "100px", "columnmenu": "false"}]
};
```

I need the above data split into array list without looping

first array list : `["SNo", "Name", "City"]`

Second array list : `["group", "sort", "filter", "type", "min", "max", "format", "group", "sort", "type", "columnmenu", "group", "type", "filter", "width", "columnmenu"]`

Third array list: `["true", "true", "true", "number", 1, 1000, "{0:c}", "true", "true", "string", "true", "true", "number", "true", "100px", "false"]`

Fourth array list : `[7, 4, 5]` // count of each attributes

Please help me. am new of this field. otherwise reduce the maximum no.of loops.

Comment: What's the problem with looping ?

Comment: I think from his last line, he has no problem with loops. He just want minimum no. of loops.

Comment: That's a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I also got something working when you can have more keys in columns object.

```
var first_array = Object.keys(column);
var second_array = []; 
var third_array = []; 
var fourth_array = [];

first_array.forEach(function(inner_key){
    var keysInInnerKey = Object.keys(column[inner_key][0]);
    var valuesInInnerKey = keysInInnerKey.map(function(key){
        return column[inner_key][0][key];
    });
second_array = second_array.concat(keysInInnerKey);
third_array = third_array.concat(valuesInInnerKey);
fourth_array.push(keysInInnerKey.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the value of the object keys, perhaps a simple function that returns a set of keys or values can do the trick.

```
function getAll(obj, type) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (type === 'keys') {
      arr.push(key);
    } else {
      arr.push(obj[key]);
    }
  }
 return arr;
}

var one = getAll(column, 'keys');
```

You can loop over the elements in the first array to get fill the rest of the arrays:

```
var two = [];
var three = [];

for (var i = 0, l = one.length; i < l; i++) {
  two.push.apply(two, getAll(column[one[i]][0], 'keys'));
  three.push.apply(three, getAll(column[one[i]][0], 'values'));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FjXuK/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/43ywb/)**

**First array:**

```
Object.keys(column)
```

**Second array:**

```
Object.keys(column['SNo'][0])
.concat(Object.keys(column['Name'][0]))
.concat(Object.keys(column['City'][0]))
```

**Third array:**

```
Object.keys(column['SNo'][0]).map(function(k){return column['SNo'][0][k]})
.concat(Object.keys(column['Name'][0]).map(function(k){return column['Name'][0][k]}))
.concat(Object.keys(column['City'][0]).map(function(k){return column['City'][0][k]}))
```

**Forth array:**

```
Object.keys(column).map(function(k){return Object.keys(column[k][0]).length})
```

No looping :) (not `for` at least....)

Comment: Thanks Kuf, But in second and third array you put the name that is SNo, Name, City like, but I don't know this column name because this data dynamically come from database. please give some other alternate solution. Thanks and advance

Comment: @Raviraj why can't you use any loops?