# Convert JSON object array into string

Tags: jquery, json

I am using jquery and I have a JSON object array and I want to convert into a string like below. I found that there is a method called "JSON.stringify" but i have no idea how to use it in my case.

```
var movies = [{"Title":"Iron Man"},{"Title":"Super Man"},{"Title":"Spider Man"}];
```

What i want is the following sting.

```
var movielist = 'Iron Man, Super Man,Spider Man';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has close relationship to another SO post. This may be what your looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432269/json-object-split-into-json-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var movielist=$.map(movies, function(o) { return o["Title"]; }).join(", ");
```

Assuming you want spaces after the commas that is. If you omit the `", "` it'll just use commas.

Comment: What is there is only values. like var movies = ["Iron Man","Super Man"]. How to covert this

Comment: Simply `movies.join(", ")`